the sticky bit prevents the contents of the file from being changed
I recently started learning Linux and the following problem arose. I have 2 users mk (has admin rights) and usr_2 (regular). In the home directory of user mk at /home/mk I created a file mk_file with permissions -rw-rw-rwx.
Next, I wanted this file to be accessible (rwx) to the user usr_2. Therefore, I created an open directory /home/all with drwxr-xrwt permissions. There I put a hard link h_mk_file. In theory, now usr_2 can edit the source file through this link, but when I try to do this (I’m using nano) it says: Error writing h_mk_file: Permission denied.
However, by changing the access rights of the all directory to drwxr-xrwx (removing the sticky bit), the error disappeared and usr_2 was able to change the file.
The question is, why does this happen and how to fix it? As far as I understand, the sticky bit prohibits all users except root and the owner from deleting the contents of a file located in the directory. Why does it somehow affect the right to change the contents of the file?
Here's a little more detail:
1 mk@mk_comp1:/home/all$ ll
2 total 20
3 drwxr-xrwt 3 root  root  4096 июл  3 13:22 ./
4 drwxr-xr-x 8 root  root  4096 июл  2 12:24 ../
5 drwxrwxr-x 2 usr_2 usr_2 4096 июл  3 12:36 dir2/
6 -rw-rw-r-- 1 usr_2 usr_2    0 июл  2 20:38 file2
7 -rw-rw-r-- 1 usr_2 usr_2   11 июл  2 20:38 file_usr_2
8 -rw-rw-rwx 2 mk    mk      12 июл  3 13:20 h_mk_file
9 -rw-rw-r-- 1 usr_2 usr_2    0 июл  3 13:20 text


Creating a file in a directory requires write access to that directory. The sticky bit is treated differently for directories as explained in man 3 chmod. Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.
